# Regarding Systools for SQL Recovery

Tags: sql-server

Has anyone else had issues with datetime column types whilst performing SQL Server MDF file recovery with the Systools SQL recovery software. I am noticing some behavior in a licensed version 11. I was recovering a corrupt MDF file. The recovery is successful except that a birth date column in a given table is restored with two arbitrary dates (1900-01-01 and 1953-01-01) all through the record set. Notably, there are other tables with even larger record set whose dates are properly restored.

Comment: This sounds like a question for their support team; this has nothing to do with programming, and the only question you ask is "has this happened to any one else?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a question for their support team.